# Extracting groups of unstructured text to for later NLP?

Tags: nlp, data-mining, text-mining, information-retrieval, information-extraction

I am new to data mining / text mining so I am not sure that I am using the right terminology. I am attempting to come up with a process to extract groups of related content to later apply NLP and other techniques to extract the meaningful data out of it. I have starting data that looks something like this:

```
Product Name - $-25- 15
Product Name - $3

Product Bundle $100
-Product 1
-Product 2 Condition
-Product 3 Condition

Product - Version - Condition $100

Product
Extras
Extras

More Info
$20 

Product
Extras
Condition
$15

Product (Condition) 50
Product (Condition) 25
Product (Condition) 10
```

The goal is to obtain a list like this with a unique entry for each "listing", grouped with relevant meta data:

```
[Product Name - $-25- 15], [Product Name - $3], [Product Bundle $100 -Product 1 -Product 2 Condition -Product 3 Condition], [Product - Version - Condition $100]
```

The full text is written by many different authors and often switches formats within a single post so I can't detect what format it is in and process the whole document. The one thing all formats have in common is that they have new line breaks rather than a dense paragraph of text. So working with that I have a few ideas on how to approach it:

**Option 1: Rudimentary**

1. Split the document into an array by new lines (\n)
2. If there is an extra empty space between entries then group the previous ones
3. If there is no extra space, detect if there is a price, if so consider it's own group

This option is very simple and could work when double spaced. However it fails by using a number as a heuristic to determine if it's a new group as the product names, extras, conditions could contain numbers when single spaced.

**Option 2: NLP**

This option would attempt to classify each word in the document as Product Name, Condition, Attribute, Price. Then process the document again to group text so that it has a Name and Price and optionally the condition and extra meta data.

The problem with this approach is that the extras and bundles are products as well so classifying them would determine that they are a unique entry with meta data when they belong under a "parent" product because of how they are spaced in the document.

**Option 3: Something else?**

My first thought was to process the document into groups first so that when NLP knows all words in this group are related to the same product. I have a list of all Product Names and a pretty good one of all Conditions. The extras, versions, and other text is unique so it may cause some issues attempting to determine how to group.

It seems like it might need a mix of the two because how the author spaces them is ultimately how everything is bundled. Yet we don't immediately know if the next set of content is related to the first or a new listing without some other process.

**INPUT**

```
Mario Party - $10

Party Games Bundle $100
-Super Mario Bros
-Mario World - NEW

Donkey Kong - 2017 Version - Used $10

Wii Sports
Includes Controllers

Also includes memory card
$10 

Grand Theft Auto
San Andreas
Includes poster
Used
$10

Zelda (Unopened box) 10
```

**OUTPUT (JSON)**

```
{ listings: [
    { name: 'Mario Party', condition: null, version: null, currency: '$', price: 10, includes: null },
    { name: 'Party Games Bundle', condition: null, version: null, currency: '$', price: 100, includes: ['Super Mario Bros', 'Mario World - NEW'] },
    { name: 'Donkey Kong', condition: 'Used', version: '2017 Version', currency: '$', price: 10, includes: null },
    { name: 'Wii Sports', condition: null, version: null, currency: '$', price: 10, includes: ['Includes Controllers', 'Also includes memory card'] },
    { name: 'Grand Theft Auto', condition: 'Used', version: 'San Andreas', currency: '$', price: 10, includes: 'Includes poster' },
    { name: 'Zelda', condition: 'Unopened box', version: null, currency: '$', price: 10, includes: null }
] }
```

Comment: Could you please share sample input data and the final output data so that we can help better.

Comment: @SidharthMacherla Thanks for your feedback. I added sample input and output data.

Answer (score 0):

If one is open to training a model and improving accuracy over a period of time, an article [here](https://www.foyi.co.nz/posts/howtoguides/customermodel/) will help in doing so.

Comment: I am open to that, but my concern with certain NLP approaches is that I don't have much training data. Over time I can gain a half dozen documents a week. It sounds like most approaches need tens of thousands to millions of documents to work effectively. While I am ok with improving accuracy over time, it may never be to the level it needs to work.